# Generate unique semi random numeric strings

Tags: arrays, powershell, random, sequential-number

I want to generate 10k of unique numbers composed of a sequential number (16 digits) followed by a random numeric string (4 digits). Weapon of choice is Powershell because it's the only tool I have a very limited knowledge of.

Problems encountered:

1. Generating 10k sequential numbers using the following method: 1400000000000000..1400000000010000 and putting into a variable. Error: Value is to large for an Int32
2. Generating 10k of 4 digit via `Get-Random -Minimum 0001 -Maximum 9999` and putting them in a variable. I manage only to obtain 1 random number.
3. Combining the two variables using the Join-Object (or at least that's what I hope could be done)

How can I combine these 3 commands to obtain a list of semi random numbers as specified above? Or is there simpler way to achieve the same result?

Comment: can you share your code so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(0..10000).ForEach{ '14000000000{0:00000}{1:0000}' -f $_, (Get-Random 10000) }
```

**Result:**

```
14000000000000004965
14000000000000010114
14000000000000026382
14000000000000038644
14000000000000045435
14000000000000052051
14000000000000061801
14000000000000077046
14000000000000087791
14000000000000098090
14000000000000102712
....
```

**Explanation:**

- Use the [Format Operator (`-f`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7#format-operator--f) to format the string, like `'14000000000{0:00000}{1:0000}'`. For details, see [composite formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting).
- You do not have to put the whole 16 digit number in a `[int32]`, just count from `0..1000` with leading zeros up to 5 digits (`{0:00000}`) and prefix it with `14000000000`
- In the second place holder (`{1:0000}`), place a new random number with leading zeros up to 4 digits

Answer (score 1):

[iRon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62580780/45375) provides an elegant solution.

Let me complement it by addressing points 1. and 2. individually:

Re 1.

`..`, the [range operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#range-operator-) supports only `[int]` (`System.Int32`) (numeric) endpoints (incidentally, the same applies to LINQ's [`Range`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Linq.Enumerable.Range) method).

You can use the `.ForEach()` array method to work around the problem, as also shown in iRon's answer.

```
# Returns a collection of [long] (System.Int64) values.
(0..10000).ForEach({ 1400000000000000 + $_ })
```

Re 2.

PowerShell [Core] now supports a `-Count` parameter for `Get-Random` that allows you to request a given number of random numbers between the specified bounds.

```
# PowerShell [Core] only
# Note that there's no point in specifying leading zeros (0001).
# The output will be an array of unformatted [int] (System.Int32) values
$10kRandomNums = Get-Random -Count 10000 -Minimum 1 -Maximum 9999
```

Note: The `-Maximum` value (unlike `-Minimum`) is *non*-inclusive; that is, the highest random number that can be returned is *1 lower*, `9998`.

In *Windows PowerShell*, you'll have to call `Get-Random` in a loop:

```
# Windows PowerShell
$10kRandomNums = foreach ($i in 1..10000) { Get-Random -Minimum 1 -Maximum 9999 }
```

Calling a cmdlet in a loop is expensive; you can speed things up noticeably by using the [`System.Random`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Random) .NET class directly:

```
$rnd = [Random]::new()
$10kRandomNums = foreach ($i in 1..10000) { $rnd.Next(1, 9999) }
```

Comment: Noted. These comments make it easier to understand single operators.

Answer (score 0):

The classic algorithm for creating an unique sequence is to put all the values into an array. Pick a value. Move the last value of the array into the place from where you just picked the value. Then decrease the array's size by one. This creates a copy of the array, so if there are lots of values, be wary of the extra cost that is caused by resizing an array.

An example that shuffles values from 0 to 19 is like so,

```
$rnd = @()
$arr = 0..19
$tail = $arr.Length-1

do {
    $pick = get-random -min 0 -max $tail
    $rnd += $arr[$pick]
    $arr[$pick] = $arr[$tail]

    $tail--
} while($tail -gt 0)
$rnd += $arr[0]
# Uncomment the next statement to print shuffled array
# $rnd -join ', '
```

Since the value doesn't fit into int32, use int64. To add the shuffled values, a loop works like so,

```
$big = @()
$seed = [int64]1400000000000000

$rnd | % {
  $big += $seed + $_
}
$big
```

## Output

```
PS C:\> $big
1400000000000015
1400000000000006
1400000000000010
1400000000000017
1400000000000009
1400000000000004
1400000000000005
1400000000000016
1400000000000014
1400000000000003
1400000000000001
1400000000000002
1400000000000013
1400000000000011
1400000000000012
1400000000000019
1400000000000000
1400000000000007
1400000000000008
1400000000000018
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to elegant and accepted [iRon's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62580780/1155121) answer here is a way to generate 26 digit serial number that is suitable for SMBIOS or chasis serial number (for example when creating virtual machine):

```
"{0:####-####-####-####}-{1:####-####-##}" -f (Get-Random -Minimum 1000000000000000 -Maximum 9999999999999999),(Get-Random -Minimum 1000000000 -Maximum 9999999999)
```

And sample output results like this:

```
5682-4527-3132-4212-5548-2660-46
6433-6848-9306-5822-1601-7101-98
6986-6609-3112-9326-3662-7689-92
```

References

- https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-f-operator.html
- https://ss64.com/ps/get-random.html